# How to find the value of an attribute constructor argument using Roslyn?

Tags: c#, roslyn

Using Roslyn, how would I find the value of the constructor of an attribute? So given the following class with an attribute:

```
[Example(typeof(ClassFromAnotherDll))]
public class ExampleClass
{
    public int JustANumber { get; set; }
}
```

And the `ExampleAttribute` would look like so (though the source would not be in the same solution as the one above):

```
public class ExampleAttribute : Attribute
{
    private readonly Type _type;

    public ExampleAttribute(Type type)
    {
        _type = type;
    }
}
```

How would I get information (e.g. properties, constructors) about the `ClassFromAnotherDll` type?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Call `GetAttributes()` on any symbol (from the semantic model) to get a list of all applied attributes.

Then look at the [`ConstructorArguments`](http://source.roslyn.io/#Microsoft.CodeAnalysis/Symbols/Attributes/CommonAttributeData.cs,40) of the attribute you want.

If the argument is a `typeof` expression, its `Value` will be an `INamedTypeSymbol`.